# forEach not working when for loop does with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, foreach

I have an array like so

```
var updates = [];
```

I then add stuff to the array like this

```
updates["func1"] = function () { x += 5 };
```

When I call the functions with a for loop it works as expected

```
for(var update in updates) {
     updates[update]();
}
```

But when I use the forEach it doesn't work!?

```
updates.forEach(function (update) {

    update();
});
```

forEach definitely works in my browser which is google chrome, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) iterates over `indexes` not over `properties`. Your code:

```
updates["func1"] = "something";
```

Adds a property to an object – that incidentally is an array – not an element to an array.
In fact, it's equivalent to:

```
updates.func1 = "something";
```

If you need something like an hashmap, then you can use a plain object instead:

```
updates = {};

updates["func1"] = "something";
```

And then iterate using `for…in`, that [shouldn't be used on arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Or you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to retrieve the properties an iterate over them:

```
Object.keys(updates).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: Thank you this helped me understand it alot better, I read I should not have used `for...in` which is why I asked the question, so thanks for the alternative to `for...in` :)

Answer (score 6):

You aren't adding the items to the array, you are adding object properties to your array object.  `for .. in` will return all properties, `forEach` only iterates over array elements.

To add to the array, you would do this:

```
updates.push(function () { x += 5 });
```

If you intend to add in the way you are, then just use an object and not an array:

```
var updates = {}
```

and then use `for ... in`.